# Serial downvoting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, serial-voting

So, 11 hours ago, 6 of my answers were downvoted all at the same time.  Now, the serial downvoting was reversed, which means 5 out of 6 of the downvotes were reversed.  **Why only 5 out of 6?**  If it is clear that someone is just downvoting to downvote, shouldn't all of them be reversed?  The person who downvoted gave all downvotes to questions with 0 votes, so now I'm stuck with an [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29559/8671) with 1 downvote and no upvotes.  This isn't a huge deal but it makes it seem like it's a bad answer when at least the OP found it helpful.

And, mods can't tell who did this, right?

Comment: It seems that down-vote on your [CW answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78906/challenging-problems-in-calculus/78960#78960) was not reversed either. (As we do not know details  about how the detection script works, we cannot be sure that it is part of the serial downvoting; but on the reputation tab in your profile this answer is shown after the one you have linked to.)

Answer (score 4):

If some votes were reversed, this means that the one vote that wasn't reversed was from a different user and not connected to the serial downvoting. You'll also notice that there is a bit larger delay between that vote and all the other ones, which were cast only seconds apart.

In my experience the serial voting script is rather thorough when it is triggered, so I'm pretty sure that the vote that wasn't reversed isn't connected to the serial downvoting.

Moderators can't help you with that as they can't see who cast a single specific vote, only SE employees have access to that kind of data.

Comment: For the record, these are the times as shown in OP's [reputation tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8671/graphth?tab=reputation&sort=time)
Not reversed: `00:58:51`
Probably not reversed (CW) `01:00:02`
Reversed: `01:00:12` `01:00:24` `01:00:44` `01:00:50` `01:00:54`\\
I don't know whether it is possible to find out for sure whether the downvote for the CW answer has been reversed or not. (It is possible that the downvote I see there now have been there already before this.)

Comment: Thanks all for your great knowledge.  I would like to point out that I have had this happen before and it was all but one vote reversed then as well.  So, are you sure that this means the vote was from another user?  Or, are you sort of guessing?  I ask with all respect.  It just seems like it would be a huge coincidence if both times I was serial downvoted, in the exact same minute or so, another user also downvoted one answer.  I found the dates.  May 17th, 4 downvotes within 2 minutes at the most.  May 18th, the last 3 are reversed.  Just as this time, the first is not reversed.

Comment: @Graphth I've encountered cases like this before, and a SE employee verified that the downvote was from another user. The script is rather aggressive when removing the votes, I doubt it would miss votes from the same user when they are a few seconds or minutes from reversed votes.

Comment: @MadScientist Okay, thanks for the info!